# `while` loop retrying inside AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have a AsyncTask which contains the following `doInBackground()` method:

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... StringUrls) {

       // ...

            while (len != -1) {

                bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = in.read(buffer);

                if (Recorder.this.isCancelled)  {

                Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                    break;
                }

            }


            bufOutstream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());


        }


       return true;
    }
```

I'd like to do the following:

- When the `while` loop is done (because `len == -1`) i would like to wait 1 second and then retry it, so then if `len` will change to `len != -1` it will be looped again.
- This retry should be done till 5 times (when `len == -1`) when `len != -1` retrying should be stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to read and write but when there is nothing more to read you want to retry 5 times with a 1 second interval and give up after 5 seconds (retries) have passed?

```
boolean retry=true;
while(retry) {
    retry = false;
    while(len != -1) {
        bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        len = in.read(buffer);
        if (Recorder.this.isCancelled){
            Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                break;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        synchronized(this) {
            try{ 
                wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException){}
        }

        len = in.read(buffer);
        if(len!=-1) {
            retry = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also say what to do when `IOException` (because of disconnection) is being called? This interrupts your loop.

Comment: It's up to you. You can simply ignore it and retry the request (5 times) but sometimes it takes some time before an IOException is thrown. Especially in cases of `SocketTimeoutException`. Another option is to retry 1 or 2 times instead of 5, when an exception is thrown. You could also try to implement some kind of Exponential backoff or even interrupt the task immediately. It really depends on how important is the data for your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... StringUrls) {

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            while (len != -1) {
                bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = in.read(buffer);
                if (Recorder.this.isCancelled)  {
                    Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                    break;
                }
            }
            bufOutstream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
       }
       return true;
    }
```